# authentication using a different table and column

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-2.3, cakephp-2.1

How to change user table name and column name for authentication in cakephp. By default its taking users as table name.

```
class AppController extends Controller {

    public $components = array(
        'Session','Security',
        'Auth' => array(
            'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'project', 'action' => 'index', 'Project Details'),
            'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login')
        )
    );



    function beforeFilter() {
        $this->Auth->allow('login');

    }
}
```

Model :

```
  App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
    class Users extends AppModel {
    var $useTable = 'manager';


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your AppController's beforeFilter() method add following code

```
function beforeFilter(){
   parent::beforeFilter();
   $this->Auth->authenticate = array(
   AuthComponent::ALL => array("fields" => array("username" => "your_username_column", "password" => "your_password_column") )
```

);
    }

Comment: how to get logged in user id and username

Comment: $this->Auth->user('id'); $this->Auth->user('username');